# Does $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(\gamma(t))}{t}=0$ imply $\displaystyle\lim_{v\to 0} \frac{g(v)}{\|v\|}=0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $g:U\subset \mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$ be a function defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$. I'd like to understand the relationship between the following three limits.

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{v\to 0} \frac{g(v)}{\|v\|}=0$
2. $\displaystyle \lim_{v\to 0} \frac{g(tv_0)}{t}=0$, for all $v_0\in\mathbb R^2$.
3. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(\gamma(t))}{t}=0$, for all differentiable path $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to U$ such that $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$.

*Remarks:*

- Limits having the form 1 appear in the definition of differentiability.
- It is clear that **1 implies 2** (what is used, for example, to prove existence of the directional derivatives of differentiable functions).
- In general, **2 does not imply 1** (what can be seen, for example, by defining $g(0,0)=0$ and $g(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ otherwise).
- Of course, 2 is a much weaker version of 3 (with $\gamma$ restrict to linear paths of the form $\gamma(t)=tv_0$).

> **Question:** Does 3 imply 1?

I couldn't prove it (for example, I'm not able to connect $|v|$ with $t$ in a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof; I also cannot see how could we find a $\delta$ that works for all $v$ inside a disk since each $\delta=\delta_\gamma$ works only for $v$ in the image of $\gamma$).

Also, I couldn't construct a counterexample. In fact, in every case that I have seen in which 1 fails, there are differentiable paths that do not satisfy the limit in 3.

Comment: If you allow for continuous paths in $3$, then $3$ implies $1$. Let's show the contraposition. Pick a sequence $(x_n)_n \subseteq U$ such that $x_n \rightarrow 0, \Vert x_n \Vert \geq 2^{-n}$ (just repeat entries is needed to ensure the second condition). Then define $\gamma(t)=x_n + (t-2^{-n})/(2^{-n-1}-2^{-n}) (x_{n+1}-x_n)$ for $t\in [-2^{-n}, -2^{-n-1})$ (linear interpolation) and $\gamma(0)=0$. Furthermore, define $\gamma(t)=\gamma(-t)$ for $t\in (0,1]$. Then $\gamma: [-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous and $\gamma(0)=0$.

Comment: Furthermore, we have $$ \frac{g(\gamma(-2^{-n}))}{2^{-n}} \geq \frac{g(x_n)}{\Vert x_n \Vert} \geq \varepsilon. $$ Thus, $1$ does not hold true. In order to get a proof for your version one would need to be able to produce a differentiable version of our curve. Clearly it is not an issue to make it differentiable away from $t=0$, but I am not sure how to show that one could make it differentiable at zero.